# A second newtcolorbox causes a missing reference with the first

Tags: tcolorbox

Here is an example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{sum}
\newtcolorbox[use counter= sum,number within=chapter,crefname={summary}{summaries},Crefname={Summary}{Summaries}]{Summary}[2][]{coltitle=white,title={\textbf{\textit{SUMMARY \thetcbcounter }}#2},#1}

%\newcounter{exp}%
%\newtcolorbox[use counter= exp,number within=chapter,crefname={ex}{exs},Crefname={Ex}{Exs}]{Example}[2][]{coltitle= white,title={\textbf{\textit{Example \thetcbcounter }}#2},#1}% 

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{a}

\begin{Summary}[label={sum:Adam}]{ TITLE.} 
Text
\end{Summary}
\Cref{sum:Adam} on \cpageref{sum:Adam}

%\begin{Example}[label={exp:Adam}]{ title }%%
%Text %%
%\end{Example}%%
%\Cref{exp:Adam} on \cpageref{exp:Adam}%%

\end{document}
```

1. As is, everything is fine.
2. If the two lines in the preamble that are marked % at the right end are uncommented,  the Cref does not work but the cpageref still does.
3. If, in addition, the four lines in the document that are marked %% at the right end are uncommented, there is no change with the Summary but both the Cref and the cpageref for the Example work...

Comment: Everything works for me, at least with this MWE. `cleveref` v0.19 and `tcolorbox`v3.80. Do you use an updated system?

Comment: I just upgraded `cleveref` to 0.19 (2013/12/28) and `tcolorbox` to 2.80 (2014/03/31). No change. For 2. and 3. I get `Cref  reference format for label type sum undefined on input line 19.`

Comment: @schremmer: No, not `tcolorbox v2.80`, Ignasi wrote `v3.80`. The `crefname` feature was added on `2014/12/01`, so this needs `v.3.34` at least. But updating to the newest version is even better. And it works out of the box

Comment: You were of course correct. All is well now. Just to mention one thing in my defense---and for the edification of others: it was TeX Live Utility which did the v2.80 upgrade and I had to do v3.80 by hand. (Perhaps because I am still running MacTeX 2013 under OS X 10.6.8.)

Comment: @schremmer: Well, we are heading towards TL 2016 ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved with a package update.